# Автоматическое обновление страницы

Tags: javascript, php

Какой надо код чтобы страница автоматически обновлялась, например мне нужно чтобы страница http://pux.mobi/?load каждые 15 секунд автоматический обновлялась с окончание на &one "http://pux.mobi/?load&one"

P.S. я пишу код обновление но он просто обновляет http://pux.mobi/?load
нужно чтобы именно &one было в конце URL

Answer (score 5):

```
var url = window.location.href;
if(url.match(/&one/))
{
    var interval = setInterval(function()
    {
        location.reload();
    }, 15000);
}
```

Comment: Используйте для проверки вхождений регулярных выражений `.test`

http://www.browserscope.org/user/tests/table/agt1YS1wcm9maWxlcnINCxIEVGVzdBixotcCDA

Comment: Привычка просто!

Comment: IndexOf еще быстрее сработает.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href += '&one'
```